# Parsing Javascript withing Html using HTML DOM PARSER

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, parsing

currently trying to parse the download link for zippyshare files in php the issue is I need to get their javascript and I am not being able to do it. This is the part of the page I need to parse:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var somdfunction = function() {
       var a = 327030;
       document.getElementById('dlbutton').omg = 327033%78956;
       var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('dlbutton').omg) * (327033%3);
       var e = function() {if (false) {return a+b+c} else {return (a+3)%b + 3}};
       document.getElementById('dlbutton').href    = "/d/91667079/"+(b+18)+"/Animals%20%28Radio%20Edit%29-www.manomuzika.net.mp3";
       if (document.getElementById('fimage')) {
           document.getElementById('fimage').href  = "/i/91667079/"+(b+18)+"/Animals%20%28Radio%20Edit%29-www.manomuzika.net.mp3";
       }
       var result = 0;
   }
</script>
```

Which being fetched from its website using:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

Basically they create the download links dynamically using javascript, I am able to get the source using my parser but I need to cut it down to getting the values of:

```
var a = 327030;
document.getElementById('dlbutton').omg = 327033%78956;
```

and finally

```
document.getElementById('dlbutton').href = "/d/91667079/"+(b+18)+"/Animals%20%28Radio%20Edit%29-www.manomuzika.net.mp3";
```

Once I am able to get these three variables from within the source I will be able to create the download link my issue at the moment is cutting it down to that.

I am using this parser:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

If you would like to see the source code I am able to parse at the moment here it is:

http://www.somf.us/music/test.php?url=http://www66.zippyshare.com/v/91667079/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use regex because simple is not a javascript parser.
Here's a hint to get you started:

```
preg_match('/var a = (\d+);/', file_get_contents($url), $m);
echo $m[1];
```